# How to access web- or usb-cam on Desktop and build in camera on Android in a Gluon Mobile Project using OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, javafx, cross-platform, gluon-mobile

I'm using Gluon Mobile 4.0.0 in Eclipse and I want to write an image processing application for Desktop and Android. I need to have direct camera access on both platforms and I would prefer using OpenCV.

So my first question would be if it's possible to use (one) OpenCV library to access the camera on different platforms?

If so, which version of OpenCV should I use and how do I use it in my Gluon Mobile application? If not, are there any other possibilities which I could try?

It would be great if someone could offer some help because I'm new to mobile development and Gluon. Thanks! :)

Comment: Can't anyone help me adding OpenCV to my project for both platforms Android and Desktop? I still have no soloution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using JavaCV 1.3 now and after a few problems it seems to work well now.

For anybody who's interested, I've edited my build.gradle like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '1.3'
    desktopCompile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:3.1.0-1.3:windows-x86_64'
    androidCompile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:3.1.0-1.3:android-arm'
}
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'org.bytedeco', module: 'javacpp-presets'
}
```

Update your project and Gradle will download all necessary files and put it in your "Gradle Dependencies" folder.